# How to create a chat application in iOS using XMPP without creating my own server. Is there any free server

Tags: chat

I want create a chat functionality in my app using XMPP but I don't have any knowledge about how to start this.
And also I don't want host any server is it any free one ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to make other people do the research for you. Try to look for a solution yourself. Once you're stuck, show us what you have so far (code wise, or even tell us what you tried and why it didn't work), and people will try and help you move forward. Try to read the some of the site's [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have ajabber.me as a sandbox server, I tested for my app and it was working great ! Also you can download Spark Client to have a UI for your chat.

Have a look at the Smack API. I used it for my Java project

First create a connection

```
AbstractXMPPConnection connection;

XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setHost("ajabber.me")
                .setServiceName("ajabber.me").setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.ifpossible).setPort(5222)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(false).build();

connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login("java","test");
```

Then create you can send a message to a user

```
Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat("someone@jabberme");
chat.sendMessage("hello");
```

It is in Java but you can easily adapt it for your language

Comment: Please provide some steps in details?

Comment: I have the steps in Java but not for iOS :/ But I can tell you that you need to create a connection to the server and then create a Chat object, then you can send a message to this chat

Comment: Please provide me how to create connection.And one more question is it free, means is there any limit for message?

Comment: I will edit my answer for the build steps, but I don't think there is a message limit as I use it only a few, but by sending a message every second for 1 hour, I didn't encoutered any problem

Comment: I have to any configuration or create any account in Smack API/ajabber.me ?

Comment: Yep, the java, test is already created, but someone@jabber.me maybe doesn't exists. And one more thing, you can't receive your own messages, so you need two users, the easiest way is to have one from your software and one you use in spark